# combining multiple regular expression substutions

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the `re` library in python:

Right now I have multiple substitutions such as:

```
sentence = re.sub(" between | for | from ", " preposition ", sentence)
sentence = re.sub(" cake | cookies ", " food ", sentence)
```

... and so on

sample input:

```
I like cookies from safeway
```

output:

```
I like food preposition safeway
```

Is there a way I can combine these in a more efficient way?

Comment: What do you mean by *efficient*? Less code? Faster runtime?

Comment: You could just write a function that takes your pattern and the substitution as an input and returns your substituted string, but the end result will be very similar to what you're doing right now.

Comment: combine. What kind of combination. Here the sentence is a variable (i.e., you have no. of sentences) or the patterns and replacements are variables or all of them.                                     `fn = lambda patt,repl,snt: re.sub(patt,repl,snt)` might help but it seems to do the similar thing.

Comment: Thanks. I was just seeing if there was a way to do in less code or more efficiently